# Anime about monsters that have elemental gems in their foreheads and can evolve like Digimon

Tags: story-identification, anime

I've been searching for an anime that was shown during my elementary school years,
around 2004-2008. The story was about monsters that have elemental gems in their foreheads. They could evolve like Digimon. Since I come from Indonesia, the anime that appears on television is anime that aired around last year or more...
I think it's one generation with *Monster Rancher*.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this a series or a movie? Were there any human characters in it? If so, what did they look like, in terms of age, sex, hair colour, etc? And can you describe the appearance or powers of any of the monsters?

Comment: Hi Fulan, you may want to take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

Might this be ***[Zinba](https://myanimelist.net/anime/31427/Zinba)*** (2013)...?

From MyAnimeList:

> The juvenile Kan from the earth is summoned to the Kingdom of Toria , where he encounters attack from the giant creature Zinba, and he's rescued by the linker Shibuki and Uranus. Later, he accidentally gets on the linker squad DUX truck to the maze valley, finding in a cave a golden Zinba.

The main character is, [Tian Yu](https://myanimelist.net/character/140123/Tian_Yu), a boy from Earth who's transported to another world, where there are various monsters with gems in their foreheads. He's aided in his adventures by Zinba, a small, yellow creature resembling a lion cub, which grows into a gigantic lion monster when a red gem is placed in an indentation on its forehead.